# cant' build docker file for my service because of pip-req file not found error

Tags: docker, microservices

i have created a Dockerfile that creates virtual env, installs all libs and activates that virtual env for further use.

the dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:9.4-slim

##################################################
#     Install Anaconda 3:
##################################################

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    --fix-missing \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    gfortran \
    git \
    wget \
    curl \
    graphicsmagick \
    libgraphicsmagick1-dev \
    libatlas-dev \
    libavcodec-dev \
    libavformat-dev \
    libgtk2.0-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    liblapack-dev \
    libswscale-dev \
    pkg-config \
    python3-dev \
    python3-numpy \
    software-properties-common \
    zip \
&& apt-get clean && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/* \
&&  curl -o miniconda_install.sh https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh \
&&  bash miniconda_install.sh -b -p ~/anaconda3 \
&&  echo 'export PATH="~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc \
&&  ~/anaconda3/bin/conda update -n base conda \
&&  rm miniconda_install.sh \
&&  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
&&  /bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc"

ENV PATH="~/anaconda3/bin:${PATH}"

##################################################
#    Setup env for current project:
##################################################
EXPOSE 1487 1488

RUN /bin/bash -c "conda create -y -n voice"

ADD erjan_environment_var_for_voice.txt /tmp/setup/requirements.txt

RUN /bin/bash -c "source activate voice"
RUN /bin/bash -c "pip install -r /tmp/setup/requirements.txt"

WORKDIR /Service

ADD Service /Service

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source activate voice && ./run.sh"]
```

when running this command:

```
sudo docker build . -t jysan_bank:dev
```

the error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /root/anaconda3/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-1mbm1qnz/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-1mbm1qnz/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-req-build-1mbm1qnz/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-req-build-1mbm1qnz/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/tokenize.py", line 447, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-req-build-1mbm1qnz/setup.py'
```

I got this dockerfile from a similar project, it runs ok. I changed the requirements.txt file to include libs i needed.

why does it not work and asking for some file tmp/pip-req?

Comment: Generally you don't create a virtual environment in Docker: the Docker image itself is isolation from other Python-based applications, and it's standard to just `pip install` into the "system" Python (and not need to manually activate the virtual environment on every container execution).

Comment: Each `RUN` command runs in an isolated shell (its own container even), so `RUN source ...` (and `RUN export ...`) is typically a no-op.  Does combining the two `source activate ...` and `pip install` commands into one `RUN` command help?